# AS3 - Check if BitmapData is completely obscured by other BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata, hittest

I'm looking to check if a BitmapData object is completely obscured by a BitmapData object. Is there something like the hitTest function but that makes sure every pixel is covered instead of any pixel?

Edit: It is important that transparent pixels are not included when checking if the object is obscured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a pretty simple solution after all! Basically what you do is just capture the pixel values of the overlapping bitmap in the rectangle area that the overlapped bitmap occupies. You then iterate over that vector of values and as long as you don't have a 0 (completely transparent pixel), then you've completely covered the bitmap underneath.

Here are the two bitmaps I used in this test:

Overlapping bitmap:
[image]

Overlapped bitmap:
[image]

Code:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

var coveredBitmapData:BitmapData = new CoveredBitmapData();
var coveringBitmapData:BitmapData = new CoveringBitmapData();


var coveringBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(coveringBitmapData, "auto", true);
var coveredBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(coveredBitmapData, "auto", true);

coveredBitmap.x = Math.random() * (stage.stageWidth - coveredBitmap.width);
coveredBitmap.y = Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight - coveredBitmap.height);

stage.addChild(coveredBitmap);
stage.addChild(coveringBitmap);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMovement);

function onMouseMovement(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    coveringBitmap.x = mouseX - (coveringBitmap.width * .5);
    coveringBitmap.y = mouseY - (coveringBitmap.height * .5);

    checkIfCovering(coveringBitmap, coveredBitmap);
}

function checkIfCovering(bitmapA:Bitmap, bitmapB:Bitmap):Boolean
{
    //bitmapA is the covering bitmap, bitmapB is the bitmap being overlapped

    var overlappedBitmapOrigin:Point = new Point(bitmapB.x, bitmapB.y);

    var localOverlappedBitmapOrigin:Point = bitmapA.globalToLocal(overlappedBitmapOrigin);

    var overlappingPixels:Vector.<uint> = bitmapA.bitmapData.getVector(new Rectangle(localOverlappedBitmapOrigin.x, localOverlappedBitmapOrigin.y, bitmapB.width, bitmapB.height));

    if(overlappingPixels.length == 0) {
        //This means that there is no bitmap data in the rectangle we tried to capture. So we are not at all covering the underlying bitmap.
        return false;
    }

    var i:uint = 0;
    for(i; i < overlappingPixels.length; ++i) {
        if(overlappingPixels[i] == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I wonder, does the code also takes care about pixels that are say 50% transparent, or 25% transparent etc ? Antialiasing a bitmap generally have such pixels. What about those ?

Comment: Btw, i tried the code, but didnot work for me. It always displays out false ? I have used 2 pngs in my library. Anything i am missing ?

Comment: Yessir, if you read the comments in my code I am checking for absolute 100 percent transparent pixels. You will have to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: I believe that the uint values in vector are RRGGBBAA so in that case you can use the last 2 digits to determine your alpha value based on the threshold you wish to respect.

Comment: Just be sure to use an unsigned bitshift (>>>) if you are inspecting the alpha digits, or you'll get crazy results that drive you crazy. So something like alphaComp = myColor >>> 24;

Answer (score 3):

So you want to see if `object2` completely covers `object1` (both Bitmaps)?

```
var left:Boolean = object2.x <= object1.x;
var top:Boolean = object2.y <= object1.y;
var right:Boolean = object2.x + object2.width >= object1.x + object1.width;
var bottom:Boolean = object2.y + object2.height >= object1.y + object1.height;


if(left && right && top && bottom)
{
    // Completely covered.
}
```

Comment: +1, but what about in the case that the covering bitmap has an alpha channel with completely transparent pixels? :O I think you'd need to draw both bitmaps to a third bitmap and do some floodfill trickery and pixel sampling, or, copy the alpha channel of the covering bitmap to the second and check to see if any original pixels remain?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the case of transparent pixels is important.

Comment: @Anonymous1 Are you saying it is important to know if the transparent pixels do or do not cover the second bitmap, or are you saying you only care if the boundaries of the bitmap object cover the boundaries of the second bitmap?

Comment: @Anonymous1 Your seemingly small edit provides way too much additional information and tampering which I won't have the time for until tonight.

Comment: @AscensionSystems It is important that if a pixel is transparent, it is not considered to be obscuring another object or being obscured by another object.

Comment: @Anonymous1 No worries; I'll try whip something up for you when I finish work if you still don't have an answer.